# Splitting business date into Day Month and year into separate columns

Tags: sql-server, date

My business intelligence tool is creating a lot of issues with calculating a variance YOY, instead, I am contemplating creating a view in my Database which will allow me to subtract two columns giving me the variance.

I am trying to wrap my head around the best way to go about this, been testing datepart, convert, cast on the date but I am sure I am going the wrong way about this.

```
select top 1
Business_date,
CONCAT(DATEPART(MM, Business_Date),'-', DATEPART(DD, Business_Date)) as 
DayMonth,
case
when DATEPART(YYYY, Business_Date) = '2019' then 2019
end
from Occupancy_Forecast;
```

I know the code above does not give me anything where i need to be as I am trying to see the best way to do this, what I am looking for is something like the attached screenshot:

I have also included a screenshot of the current table I am reading from so you understand the current format

[image: Required look]

[image: Current Table]

Comment: So your data is stored in a denormalised format? I *assume*, therefore, that columns will continually be added for each year? Is so, you'll need a dynamic pivot; however, ideally you should be normalising your data.

Comment: I have normalized tables containing all the above data as well, the above occupancy forecast is a calculation table denormalizing the tables so I can use it to report better however I can always pivot off the normalized base tables as well - let me try

Comment: Not sure what you're aim is here then. better labelling your sample data (and providing it as DDL and DML, not an image) and your expected results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Larnu statement regarding the pivot I have been able to create a view stored containing the data required using the below to give me the desired output:

```
select Resort as Resort, Business_Date as Date, [2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], 
[2020] 
from
(select Resort, business_date, DATEPART(YYYY, Business_Date) as Year, ADR
from Occupancy_Forecast
where Business_Date > '2015-12-31') as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(ADR)
FOR YEAR IN ([2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], [2020] ) 
) as PivotTable
```